# Select2JS - there is a default value in my list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I use select2js in its last version, but I don't know why, I have a "s" by default in my list when I click in. It uses Ajax call, and I put `minimumInputLength` to 2 to avoid this. Here is my call :

```
$('.search-location').select2({
    language: 'fr',
    placeholder: "Ville ou CP",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    maximumSelectionLength: 4,
    width: '100%',
    ajax: {
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: "json",
        data: function (params) {
            var queryParameters = {
                q: params.term,
                action: 'get_the_locations'
            }
            return queryParameters;
        },
        cache: false,           
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.label,
                        id: item.number
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    }
}).on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
});
```

You can test here : https://www.cabinet-hermes.fr/ on the main search bar, the input called "VILLE, CP ou DEPARTEMENT". Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if you have a specific question or you are just telling us that there's an 's'... but what does the console show you when you log `data` inside `processResults` function?

Comment: Yes thanks, but if you read my question and know the plugin, I put a minimum limit to call the `data`. So it's not a problem of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a version higher than V4 you could try adding to your options :

```
language: { inputTooShort: function () { return ''; } }
```

That way if the user inputs less than 2 characters nothing will appear.

I obviously don't have enough elements to reproduce your problem, but that's the most general way of removing any unneeded options in select2.

Comment: Ok you made a point, but this will only remove the message, not the fact the list is opened with empty message. But because of you, I found it : https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1511

Comment: @VincentDecaux happy to help!